# Convert chars to ints and add them in C

Tags: c, pointers

Im trying to add numbers based on users char input.  If the user enters 2, i want to assign my variable x the number 2;  Then if the user enter 4, i want my variable y the number 4. If they enter t, I want to assign z the number 10.  then add 2 + 4 + 10 and output answer = 16.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(){
char a,b,c;
int numbers;
int answer;
int x,y,z;
printf("How many numbers would you like to add? (2-3): ");
scanf(" %d", &numbers);

printf("\nEnter value of your numbers. (2-9), T (for 10)\n");
scanf(" %c %c %c", &a, &b, &c);


if(numbers == 3){
    if(a == "2"){
    x = 2;
    }
    if(a == "3"){
    x = 3;
    }
    if(a == "4"){
    x = 4;
    }
    if(a == "5"){
    x = 5;
    }
    if(a == "6"){
    x = 6;
    }
    if(a == "7"){
    x = 7;
    }
    if(a == "8"){
    x = 8;
    }
    if(a == "9"){
    x = 9;
    }
    if(a == "T" || a =="t"){
    x = 10;
    }

        if(b == "2"){
        y = 2;
        }
        if(b == "3"){
        y = 3;
        }
        if(b == "4"){
        y = 4;
        }
        if(b == "5"){
        y = 5;
        }
        if(b == "6"){
        y = 6;
        }
        if(b == "7"){
        y = 7;
        }
        if(b == "8"){
        y =8;
        }
        if(b == "9"){
        y = 9;
        }
        if(b == "T" || b =="t"){
        y = 10;
        }

            if(c == "2"){
            z = 2;
            }
            if(c == "3"){
            z = 3;
            }
            if(c == "4"){
            z = 4;
            }
            if(c == "5"){
            z = 5;
            }
            if(c == "6"){
            z = 6;
            }
            if(c == "7"){
            z = 7;
            }
            if(c == "8"){
            z = 8;
            }
            if(c == "9"){
            z = 9;
            }
            if(c == "T" || c =="t"){
            z = 10;
            }
    printf("\nA = %c B = %c C = %c", a, b, c);
    printf("\nx = %d y = %d z = %d", x, y, z);
    answer = x + y + z;
    printf("\nAnswer = %d\n",  answer); 
}


return 0;
}
```

And my output is:

```
How many numbers would you like to add? (2-3): 3

Enter value of your numbers. (2-9), T (for 10)
2 4 T

A = 2 B = 4 C = T
x = 0 y = 4195472 z = 0
Answer = 4195472
```

I also get this warning:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

Comment: Have a look at 'switch' statement fr.o.m. the dokumentation! IT is a good idea to use i stead of manu if statements:)

Comment: If you have a solution where you are cutting & pasting code and changing one little bit of code in each pasted piece of code, you are almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: C and pointers are pretty nuanced and unfortunately you really need to tackle them head-on. I don't think it's feasible to just say "oh I'm going to learn C and I guess I'll learn about pointers along the way". It's more like "oh... I can barely code anything without knowing memory and pointers, guess I need to sit down and read about them first". You might also want to practice programming patterns in a higher order language along-side learning about low level stuff like C pointers.

Comment: Awww. This is horrible. Please spend some time learning C on your own following some tutorials and preferably a good book. You have made very fundamental mistakes.

Comment: This is comparing a character with the memory address of a string: `a == "4"`

Comment: Also, note that `int n = '10'-'0';` produces the `10` integer value. Look at ASCII table/`atoa()`/`itoa()` (around internet pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing single characters ('2', etc.) to string pointers ("2", etc.)  Very different things

Try:

```
if (a == '2') {
  x = 2;
}
```

and so on.

Comment: yup, thats what it was.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, @GetKnighted: please just **don't do this.** You have better (more concise, more readable, conceptually correct) options to convert strings to integers.

Comment: `atoi`, for starters: http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/stdlib.h/atoi.php

Comment: @GetKnighted In the very first place, Chris suggested you to subtract `'0'` from the character in the case of a single-character value. Then we have things like `strtol()`, `strtoul()`, `strtoll()` and `strtoull()`.

Comment: Is there a way to reset the variables after the addition?

Answer (score 2):

No need for a switch or comparison at all.  For single digit input in a `char`, simply subtract `'0'` and cast the result to an `int`.

For robustness you may want to do a range check first, ie verify that the character is >= '0' and <= '9'.

Comment: Don't even cast to `int`. It will be an `int` anyway.

Comment: Chris: that's not true. 1. What's an "implicit cast"? There's no such thing. Casts are explicit by definition. Maybe you meant "implicit conversion". 2. "the difference of two `char`s is a `char` not an `int`." - well, because of usual arithmetic conversions, the difference of two `char`s **is** an `int`. But here, we don't even have two `char`s. We have a `char` and an `int` (character literals are of type `int`).

Comment: I did, this was just a snippet to get my point across.  Thanks for the advice!